# File in use can't be accessed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an application like a desktop. I'm trying to have a background image for the desktop, but im received an error.

Below is the button to choose a background image

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = bit;
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"frame.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

And this is how I save it when you close and reopen the app (On Form1 Void)

```
if (File.Exists(@"frame.jpeg"))
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"frame.jpeg");
else
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black; //Blank
```

I'm getting an error on the line `pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"frame_backup.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);`, where it says the image is in use.

I tried doing `PictureBox1.Image = null;` to clear the image from picture but it still errors!

Comment: Try disposing the bitmap with bit.Dispose()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576341/open-image-from-file-then-release-lock

Comment: It says Parameter is not valid.
On the following line pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"frame.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: What have you changed? We're not wizards, you'll have to be more detailed...

Comment: I just disposed the bit?

Comment: 2 solutions were presented to you. Was I expected to guess?

Comment: Have a look at my solution please.

Answer (score 0):

It's still in memory, setting the picturebox to nothing won't solve anything because it doesn't *dispose* it from memory. To do that, you can use the .Dispose() method.

So....

```
bit.Dispose();
```

Comment: It says Parameter is not valid. On the following line pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"frame.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Comment: After i disposed the bit

Comment: You have to save it before you dispose of it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said you should dispose the `BitMap` object when you are done with it.
One more cleaner way of disposing this BitMap object is to include within the `using` block as BitMap implements `IDisposable` (via Its base class `Image`).

```
using(Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName))
{
        pictureBox1.Image = bit;
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"frame.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

**EDITED**

```
    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    Bitmap bitNew = new Bitmap(bit);
    bit.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = bmpNew;
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"frame.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bitNew.Dispose();
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: May be this would help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813633/a-generic-error-occurs-at-gdi-at-bitmap-save-after-using-savefiledialog

Comment: Are you trying to say the  directory doesnt exist that im trying to save in? Is there away to save it in C:\Program Files (x86) because im sure it has administration control, But its a good and safe way to say the applications files?

Comment: Well, first, can you post the stacktrace in the exception. Also look at the HResult/ErrorCode property in the exception. I dont think It needs to be saved in the Program Files.

Comment: at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at Sinox_4.Desktop_Frame.button1_Click_2(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Harry\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Sinox 4\Sinox 4\Desktop_Frame.cs:line 108

Comment: Did you also see the HResult/ErrorCode in the ExternalException?

Comment: Im new to C#, How would i get that? is it in a catch block?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Can you try the new code I added?

Comment: I still get a error on the save line Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: Is there anything more you can guide me towards to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Form your code it looks to me that you are interested to open an image, say in `PNG` format and save it as `JPEG` format. You should try like this:

Idea behind this answer is to use `using` block which helps to dispose resource as soon as it is no longer in use, and release the opened resource by getting it from the owner (see ReleaseInUseResource` function).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ReleaseInUseResource();

            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(open.FileName))
            {
                bmp.Save(@"frame.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"frame.jpeg");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"frame.jpeg"))
        {
            ReleaseInUseResource();
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"frame.jpeg");
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black; //Blank
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseInUseResource()
    {
        Image img = pictureBox1.Image;  // Get image used to display in picture box.
        if (img != null) img.Dispose(); // release it first if there is an image opened.
    }
```

Hope it helps!