# Image to byte array - ExternalException

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to read an image from an EID with a card reader and convert it to a byte array for database storage.

Reading the image works perfectly. I'm able to retreive a valid image with these properties:
[image]

However, I cannot convert it to a byte array. I'm using this code, although I've tried other approaches to convert it already:

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(Image image)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    return stream.ToArray();

}
```

Calling the Save method gives following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code
```

The details of the exception does not clear anything up. It's a general exception with no information about what went wrong.

Any ideas what I've been doing incorrectly?

Comment: Even when disposing the images and the stream, I'm still having this issue. Everything is checked in that list.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16576471/253938

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813633/a-generic-error-occurs-at-gdi-at-bitmap-save-after-using-savefiledialog

Comment: By the way, what is an "EID"?

Comment: Elektronic Identity Card :)

Comment: try saving it as JPEG because the RAW format refers to JPEG

Comment: I've tried all formats already :(

Comment: Maybe the Bitmap provided by that card reader software has some kind of dependency on something? Does the card reader software provide alternative ways of reading the image or any options that can be played with?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've already tried cloning the image and working on that instance already..

Comment: Oh dear. Create a new Bitmap of the same size and copy the pixels with programming? Or display the image on the screen and take a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You might be using a wrong `ImageFormat`

In **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)** documentation, it's mentioned that `ExternalException` will be thrown if calling `.Save()` with a wrong `ImageFormat`

you can be more generic and cover more image types if you change `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp` to `image.RawFormat`

**example:**

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(Image image)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
    return stream.ToArray();

}
```

---

> [image]